# Does Fastlane support removing a version from submission?

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-deliver

Does Fastlane support rejecting a version and replacing it with a newly submitted binary? In other words I want to be able to submit a version from my lane, but then if I want I would run the same lane again and have a new version submitted instead of the previous one.

Comment: provide fast file.

Comment: you may write build increment script in fast file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet as far as I know. But right now there is a PR that adds some related functionality:

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/pull/10722/files#diff-64843dee7bf6cf0342bd0e57d9b43c2bR1034

This could probably be used to create an action that supports what you need. Best create an issue on Github for Fastlane where you describe exactly how it should work.